# Infinite Loop In Imacro

Tags: javascript, imacros

What I'm doing here is extracting the first eight items and auto-clicking next page. Now I want to make it continuously extract the first eight items and auto-click next page and extract the first eight items again. I tried to make code for that but I failed to do that it is only running one time and extracting the first eight items and it auto-clicks next page. How can I make it to work continuously?

```
  var macro1;    
  macro1 =  "CODE:";    
  macro1 +=  "SET !LOOP 3" + "\n";     
  macro1 +=  "TAG XPATH=.//*[@id='dle-content']/div[1]/div[{{i}}]/div/div[2]/h1/a EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";     
  macro1 +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\ FILE=software.txt" + "\n";    

  macro2 ="CODE:";    
  macro2 +="URL GOTO={{link}}"+"\n";    


  var macro3;    
  macro3 =  "CODE:";    
  macro3 +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Suivant EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n";     

  for(var i = 1; i < 9; i++)     
  {     
      iimDisplay(i); iimSet("i", i);     
      iimPlay(macro1);     
  }    
  iimPlay(macro3)    

  var link=iimGetLastExtract();    

  //if there is such a link go to it    
  if(link!="#EANF#")    
  {    
      iimSet("link",link);    
      iimPlay(macro2)    

  }    


  link=iimGetLastExtract();    



  //if there is not a link like that extract link with text next    
  if(link=="#EANF#")    
  {    

      iimSet("link",link);    
      iimPlay(macro3)    

      var next_link=iimGetLastExtract();    

      //if there is a link with text next navigate to it    
      if(next_link!="#EANF#")    
      {    

          //navigate to link with text     
          iimSet("link",next_link)    
          iimPlay(macro2)    

      }    

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an infinite loop as follows:

```
// the first part of your code here

while (true) {
  for(var i = 1; i < 9; i++)     
  {     
      iimDisplay(i); iimSet("i", i);     
      iimPlay(macro1);     
  }    
  iimPlay(macro3) 

  // the rest of your code

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.It is working according to me now.